# LLVM assertion when creating a closure with `move`

Tags: rust

I have tried to create a mutable reference to clone from captured variable. But compiler said:

```
rustc: /home/rustbuild/src/rust-buildbot/slave/nightly-linux/build/src/llvm/lib/IR/Instructions.cpp:2522:
  static llvm::CastInst* llvm::CastInst::CreatePointerCast(llvm::Value*, llvm::Type*, const llvm::Twine&, llvm::Instruction*):
  Assertion `S->getType()->isPtrOrPtrVectorTy() && "Invalid cast"' failed.
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
fn foo(t: &mut int){
    println!("{}", t);
}

fn main() {
    let test = 10;

    let h = move || {
        let mut r = &mut test.clone();
        foo(r);
    };

    h();
}
```

Comment: rustc version rustc 0.13.0-nightly (62fb41c32 2014-12-23 02:41:48 +0000)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely a bug in the compiler which causes LLVM to crash (the assertion happens in LLVM code, not in Rust - otherwise there would be corresponding message and a possibility to get a backtrace). I've submitted a ticket [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/20193), you can subscribe to it to follow its progress.

Comment: From that bug report: "The workaround here is to annotate the closure (`move |:|`) to make the compiler give you an unboxed closure"